# Does Google App Engine allow adult content?

Tags: google-app-engine, adult-content

I am going to make a social photo album site with explicit adult content. I am wondering whether Google allows adult content/sites to be hosted on GAE? If so can you show some examples? if not, where is it formally stated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[It is prohibited](http://code.google.com/appengine/program_policies.html).

> **Prohibited Content**
>   The Content displayed and/or processed
>   through your Application or other web site utilizing the Service shall
>   not contain any of the following types of content:
>
> - Content that infringes a third party's rights (e.g., copyright)
>     according to applicable law;
> - ***Pornographic, obscene or excessively profane content***;
> - Hate-related or violent content;
> - Content advocating racial or ethnic intolerance;
> - Content intended to advocate or advance computer hacking or
>     cracking;
> - Gambling; Other illegal activity, including without limitation
>     illegal export of controlled substances or illegal software;
> - Drug paraphernalia;
> - Phishing;
> - Malicious content;
> - Other material, products or services that violate or encourage
>     conduct that would violate any criminal laws, any other applicable
>     laws, or any third-party rights.

Comment: Plus one for doing someone else's homework for them. ;^)

Comment: I was working under the assumption that they had looked and couldn't find it. I know every once in a while I miss something that's right in front of my nose.

Comment: The "Acceptable Use Policy" has been updated. See the other response or simply click on the link

Answer (score 12):

Apparently, the [Acceptable Use Policy](http://code.google.com/appengine/program_policies.html) has changed and now adult content is allowed.

[Greg D'Alesandre, Senior Product Manager for Google App Engine](https://plus.google.com/116333290923912560988/posts) has even stated it explicitly [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/1f282a23f57d32d8/a70c49fedcc03a79):

> I was wondering when someone was gonna notice.  This was not a mistake.
>    The new policy does not prohibit pornography nor gambling.  The policy was
>   written to disallow illegal activities but to be flexible in terms of the
>   sorts of businesses people are trying to build.  While you need to talk to
>   your own lawyers about the legality of the business you build, pornography
>   as a whole is no longer disallowed from acceptable use.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to correct the answer above with new information: It is now not explicitly forbidden. This is new as of the advent of Google Cloud Platform; You can read their [Acceptable Use Policy](https://cloud.google.com/terms/aup?csw=1) for full details.